# Table Search Cobol Issue

Tags: cobol

My program is supposed to accept a character and check it against a table that is populated with upper and lowercase versions of the alphabet. Then its supposed to display the position that letter has in the alphabet. D = 4. I'm obviously doing something wrong but I cannot for the life of me figure out what.

Table definition below.

```
    01 WS-ALPHABET-TABLE-DATA.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Aa'.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Bb'.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Cc'.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Dd'.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Ee'.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Ff'.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Gg'.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Hh'.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Ii'.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Jj'.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Kk'.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Ll'.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Mm'.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Nn'.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Oo'.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Pp'.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Qq'.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Rr'.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Ss'.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Tt'.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Uu'.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Vv'.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Ww'.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Xx'.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Yy'.
    05 FILLER                  PIC X(02) VALUE 'Zz'.

01 FILLER REDEFINES WS-ALPHABET-TABLE-DATA.
    05 WS-ALPHABET-TABLE  OCCURS 26 TIMES 
        INDEXED BY C.
        10  ALPHABET-CHAR   PIC X(02).
01  ALPHABET-NUM            PIC 99 VALUE ZEROS. 

01 CHAR PIC X.
   88 VALIDCHAR VALUE "A" THRU "Z", "a" THRU "z".
```

Rest of the code

```
0000-DRIVER.
    PERFORM 0100-INITIALIZE.
    PERFORM 1000-CHAR-TEST.
    PERFORM 9000-CLOSE.
    GOBACK.

0100-INITIALIZE.
    ACCEPT CURRENT-DATE FROM DATE.
    MOVE CURRENT-YEAR TO WS-FORMATTED-DATE-YY.
    MOVE CURRENT-MONTH TO WS-FORMATTED-DATE-MM.
    MOVE CURRENT-DAY TO WS-FORMATTED-DATE-DD.
    DISPLAY 'HW15  RACHEL GRAHAM  ' WS-FORMATTED-DATE.
    PERFORM VARYING C FROM 1 BY 1
                    UNTIL C > 26
    DISPLAY ALPHABET-CHAR(C)
    END-PERFORM.

    PERFORM 1500-ACCEPT.


1000-CHAR-TEST.
    IF CHAR = ' ' THEN
        PERFORM 1300-NO-CHAR
    ELSE
        IF  VALIDCHAR
            PERFORM 1200-VALID-CHAR
        ELSE
            PERFORM 1100-INVALID-CHAR
        END-IF    
    END-IF.    

1100-INVALID-CHAR.
    DISPLAY 'CHARACTER IN: ' CHAR.
    DISPLAY 'NOT A LETTER IN THE ALPHABET'.

1200-VALID-CHAR.
    SET C TO 1.
    SEARCH WS-ALPHABET-TABLE
        WHEN ALPHABET-CHAR (C) = CHAR
        SET ALPHABET-NUM TO C
        DISPLAY CHAR 'IS NUMBER ' ALPHABET-NUM 'IN THE ALPHABET'
        END-SEARCH.


1300-NO-CHAR.
    DISPLAY 'CHARACTER IN: " "' CHAR.
    DISPLAY 'NO CHARACTER ENTERED'.

1500-ACCEPT.
    ACCEPT CHAR.

9000-CLOSE.
    GOBACK.

STOP RUN.
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: @James nothing.

Comment: What is `CHAR`?

Comment: @user207421 its what the accepted character is stored in

Comment: Accepted and stored by what code? And where is its declaration?

Comment: @user207421  Ill edit the intial post to include that

Comment: So how is a PIC X ever going to be equal to a PIC X(2)?

Comment: @user207421 honestly its an example from a book and i adapted it poorly.

Comment: Irrelevant. The point is to get you to understand. The only way a PIC X can be equal to a PIC X(2) is if the latter contains a trailing space, and none of them do. This is rather basic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is  **CHAR** ??? if it is a single character say

```
     03  CHAR            pic X.
```

you are comparing a 2 character field to a 1 character field
try changing the table to

```
01 FILLER REDEFINES WS-ALPHABET-TABLE-DATA.
   05 WS-ALPHABET-TABLE  OCCURS 52 TIMES 
      INDEXED BY C.
      10  ALPHABET-CHAR   PIC X(01).
01  ALPHABET-NUM            PIC 99 VALUE ZEROS.
```

and the search to

```
SET C TO 1.
SEARCH WS-ALPHABET-TABLE
    WHEN ALPHABET-CHAR (C) = CHAR
    SET ALPHABET-NUM TO C
    compute ALPHABET-NUM  = (ALPHABET-NUM + 1) / 2
    end-compute
    DISPLAY CHAR 'IS NUMBER ' ALPHABET-NUM 'IN THE ALPHABET'
END-SEARCH.
```

alternatively you could change the table to

```
01 FILLER REDEFINES WS-ALPHABET-TABLE-DATA.
   05 WS-ALPHABET-TABLE  OCCURS 26 TIMES 
      INDEXED BY C.
      10  UPPER-CHAR   PIC X(01).
      10  LOWER-CHAR   PIC X(01).
```

and the search

```
SEARCH WS-ALPHABET-TABLE
    WHEN UPPER-CHAR (C) = CHAR or LOWER-CHAR (c) = CHAR
    SET ALPHABET-NUM TO C
    DISPLAY CHAR 'IS NUMBER ' ALPHABET-NUM 'IN THE ALPHABET'
END-SEARCH.
```

Comment: CHAR is a PIC X . I tried out what you suggested and it works but not passed N and now it only tests the upper case. @Bruce

Comment: *not passed N* - did you increase the occurs to **52** ??? anyway I provided second option

Comment: @streetteam you should think about accepting the answer